# Implementing a set cover data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++11, set

I want to implement a data structure which represents the abstract data type ["cover of a set"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_%28mathematics%29). The elements of the set are represented by integer indices, and so are the subsets. Each element `uint64_t e` is assigned to at least one but possibly multiple subsets `uint64_t s`. This can be implemented by storing the subset indices in a `std::vector`. The number of subsets to which any element will be assigned is usually much smaller than the total number of elements.

Performance (time and memory) is important, so which implementation would you recommend?

1. `std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>>`
2. `std::vector<std::unordered_set<uint64_t>>`
3. `std::vector<std::set<uint64_t>>`
4. anything else?

Frequent operations include:

- assigning an element to a subset
- removing an element from a subset (and possibly moving it to another)
- checking whether an element is a member of a particular subset
- getting all the subsets to which an element belongs
- efficient iteration over all elements of a particular subset would be nice, but I believe this conflicts with other goals

Comment: The performance depends on the operations you want to perform on this data structure. Please give more information about your use cases.

Comment: @nosid Added frequent operations.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest (in terms of implementation time) would be a pair of data structures:

```
std::vector< std::unordered_set<X> > set_to_elements;
std::unordered_map< X, std::unordered_set<std::size_t> > element_to_sets;
```

with the two kept coherent.  `boost` multi index containers may be able to do this bi directional stuff a bit more efficiently.

assigning an element to a subset

```
set_to_elements[subset].insert(element);
element_to_sets[element].insert( subset );
```

removing an element from a subset (and possibly moving it to another)

```
set_to_elements[subset].erase(element);
element_to_sets[element].erase( subset );
```

checking whether an element is a member of a particular subset

```
return set_to_elements[subset].find(element) != set_to_elements[subset].end();
```

or
return element_to_sets[element].find(subset) != element_to_sets[element].end();
getting all the subsets to which an element belongs

```
return element_to_sets[element];
```

efficient iteration over all elements of a particular subset would be nice, but I believe this conflicts with other goals

```
return set_to_elements[subset];
```

All operations are constant time and linear memory.  Memory and time requirements are roughly double what a compact one that requires only one of the last two above.

Micro optimizations to cache the result of `[]` operations should be done in real code if it is actually performance sensitive.  Storing iterators from one container to the other, to make operation #1 and #2 faster, are optional, and might make them a touch faster, but I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to read the paper [***Segmented Iterators and Hierarchial Algorithms***](http://lafstern.org/matt/segmented.pdf) by Matt Austern. He discusses how to efficiently process **hierarchial data structures** of the form `container<container<T>>`. One problem that needs to be solved is iterating as if you have a flat `container<T>`. For this, the Standard Library algorithms need to be specialized for so-called **segmented iterators**.

A segmented iterator is a two-level data structure that -apart from performing top-level iteration- also contains a local iterator to go one level deeper. Because these local iterators themselves can also be segmented iterators, this allows arbitrarily nested data structures (such as trees and graphs).

A set cover for a discrete set can be constructed as `std::vector<std::set<T>>`. To apply STL algorithms to such a container is either cumbersome or requires segmented iterators and hierarchial algoritms. Unfortunately, neither the Standard Library nor Boost actually implement this, so you have some work to do there.